# Вывод данных из базы Mysql в textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

Пишу простенький чат. Пользователь вводит "ник" и сообщение. В базу записывается то, что он ввел +дата/время. Как сделать так, чтобы в этом же *php* файле данные, записываемые в базу выводились из нее в *textarea*?

Примерно хочу чтобы выводило так:

1. время
2. Ник
3. сообщение
4. Пустая строка

Просто лазила в сети но, что не находила, не могла подогнать, чтобы работало.

php:

```
If (isset($_POST['login'])) $name=$_POST['login'];
If (isset($_POST['message'])) $mes=$_POST['message'];
$db=mysql_connect("localhost","Chat","12345");
mysql_select_db("chat",$db);
$dat=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mail (date, name, message) VALUES ('$dat', 
'$name', '$mes') " ); 

If ($result=='true')
{
Echo "Информация в базу добавлена успешно";
}
Else
{
Echo "Информация в базу не добавлена ";
}
```

html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chat.css">
    <a href="chat.php"></a>
    <title>Мини-чат</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Чат<img src='refresh.png'/></h1>
    <form action="chat.php" method="post">

       <table>
           <tr>
               <td colspan="2"><textarea class="t1" rows="10">

            </textarea></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
               <td><label for="login-field">Ваше имя:</label></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="login" id="login-field">
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">Ваше Сообщение:</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="message" id="message-field" style="width:250px;">
                   </tr>
                   <tr >
                       <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="send" id="send-field" class="t2"></td>
                       </tr>
           </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону ajaх или comet и подобных технологий. Т.к. без этого вам нужно перезагружать страницу, чтобы выполнить ещё один  запрос к БД и отобразить изменения.

Comment: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world